# Transforming and Reading json files in Azure Synapse notebook

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have below Json in one of my storage account and I am able to read it by following the below code. I need help in reading the columns where "pod" has value "kube-apiserver-78" or "kube-apiserver-79" and username has "system:serviceaccount:xyz" or "system:serviceaccount:poq" : can someone help me how can I translate it below code.

```
df = spark.read.json('abfss://insights-logs-kube-audit@azogs.dfs.core.windows.net/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/5IS/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV/y=2022/m=08/d=09/h=11/m=00/')

df.show()
```

Sample Json file in Storage container Which I read:

```
{ "operationName": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read", "category": "kube-audit", "ccpNamespace": "5f", "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/SID/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV", "properties": {"log":"{\"kind\":\"Event\",\"apiVersion\":\"audit.k8s.io/v1\",\"level\":\"Metadata\",\"auditID\":\"b7b1ca3\",\"stage\":\"ResponseComplete\",\"requestURI\":\"/apis/chaos-mesh.org/v1alpha1/namespaces/ve/httpchaos?limit=500\",\"verb\":\"list\",\"user\":{\"username\":\"system:serviceaccount:xyz\",\"uid\":\"3eb35e\",\"groups\":[\"system:serviceaccounts\",\"system:serviceaccounts:internal-services\",\"system:authenticated\"]},\"sourceIPs\":[\"100.100.100.100\"],\"userAgent\":\"ktl/v1.18.10 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/62c\",\"objectRef\":{\"resource\":\"httpchaos\",\"namespace\":\"vo\",\"apiGroup\":\"chaos-mesh.org\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1alpha1\"},\"responseStatus\":{\"metadata\":{},\"code\":200},\"requestReceivedTimestamp\":\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.140759Z\",\"stageTimestamp\":\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.146101Z\",\"annotations\":{\"authentication.k8s.io/legacy-token\":\"system:serviceaccount:ixyzr\",\"authorization.k8s.io/decision\":\"allow\",\"authorization.k8s.io/reason\":\"RBAC: allowed by ClusterRoleBinding \\\"admin\\\" of ClusterRole \\\"cluster-admin\\\" to ServiceAccount \\\"abc/xyz\\\"\"}}\n","stream":"stdout","pod":"kube-apiserver-78"}, "time": "2022-05-23T13:45:13.0000000Z", "Cloud": "AzureCloud", "Environment": "prod", "UnderlayClass": "hcp-underlay", "UnderlayName": "h-24"}
{ "operationName": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read", "category": "kube-audit", "ccpNamespace": "5f", "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/SID/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV", "properties": {"log":"{\"kind\":\"Event\",\"apiVersion\":\"audit.k8s.io/v1\",\"level\":\"Metadata\",\"auditID\":\"b7b1cax3\",\"stage\":\"ResponseComplete\",\"requestURI\":\"/apis/chaos-mesh.org/v1alpha1/namespaces/ve/httpchaos?limit=500\",\"verb\":\"list\",\"user\":{\"username\":\"system:serviceaccount:xyz\",\"uid\":\"3eb35e\",\"groups\":[\"system:serviceaccounts\",\"system:serviceaccounts:internal-services\",\"system:authenticated\"]},\"sourceIPs\":[\"100.100.100.100\"],\"userAgent\":\"ktl/v1.18.10 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/62c\",\"objectRef\":{\"resource\":\"httpchaos\",\"namespace\":\"vo\",\"apiGroup\":\"chaos-mesh.org\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1alpha1\"},\"responseStatus\":{\"metadata\":{},\"code\":200},\"requestReceivedTimestamp\":\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.140759Z\",\"stageTimestamp\":\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.146101Z\",\"annotations\":{\"authentication.k8s.io/legacy-token\":\"system:serviceaccount:ixyzr\",\"authorization.k8s.io/decision\":\"allow\",\"authorization.k8s.io/reason\":\"RBAC: allowed by ClusterRoleBinding \\\"admin\\\" of ClusterRole \\\"cluster-admin\\\" to ServiceAccount \\\"abc/xyz\\\"\"}}\n","stream":"stdout","pod":"kube-apiserver-78"}, "time": "2022-05-23T13:45:13.0000000Z", "Cloud": "AzureCloud", "Environment": "prod", "UnderlayClass": "hcp-underlay", "UnderlayName": "h-24"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To query `Json` file After reading it convert it into temporal tables in Apache Spark and query them using Spark SQL.

To convert it into temporal table, use command:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Name for temporal table")
```

Then query on this temporal table using Spark SQL.

```sql
SELECT * FROM "Name for temporal table"
WHERE (pod = 'kube-apiserver-78' or pod = 'kube-apiserver-79') 
and (username = 'system:serviceaccount:xyz' or username = 'system:serviceaccount:poq')
```

**Reference:** [Query JSON Files with Azure Synapse Analytics Notebooks](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/query-json-files-with-azure-synapse-analytics/)

Comment: The above query points to a syntax error on FROM "LogTable" . Here is my full query:

SELECT * FROM LogTable WHERE (pod = 'kube-apiserver-78' or pod = 'kube-apiserver-79') 
and (username = 'system:serviceaccount:xyz' or username = 'system:serviceaccount:poq')

Comment: I manage to run command by using  spark.sql("SELECT * FROM TempTable") . However, when inserting the filtering condition as per your answer it gives error as cannot recognize pod. I guess we are doing the extraction wrong here.

Comment: may be this can because of this feilds are in nested array

Comment: exactly so I need code where I can get the filtering on nested keys